# python: convert telnet application to ssh

Tags: python, security, ssh, telnet

I write a python telnet client to communicate with a server through telnet. However, many people tell me that it's no secure. How can I convert it to ssh? Should I need to totally rewrite my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a TCP tunnel via SSH and relay all the data through there, no need to reinvent the wheel. You can find examples in SSH docs under TCP tunneling (`man ssh` for instance).

But if you really want to rewrite it, then check out [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) project.

Answer (score 1):

While Telnet is insecure, it's essentially just a serial console over a network, which makes it easy to code for. SSH is much, much more complex. There's encryption, authentication, negotiation, etc to do. And it's *very* easy to get wrong in spectacular fashion.

There's nothing wrong with Telnet *per se*, but if you can change things over the network - and it's not a private network - you're opening yourself up for trouble.

Assuming this is running on a computer, why not restrict the server to localhost? Then ssh into the computer and telnet to localhost? All the security with minimal hassle.

Comment: I telnet to a BBS. People usually use telnet connecting to that BBS. I'm writing a robot to communicate with it. Thus it's not local.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a telnet *server*. If it's a client, you have no choice but to use the protocol they support. Yes your password would be visible that way, but there's nothing to do about it.

Comment: But the server support ssh, too. I think that will be OK for most people use telnet to connect it, and the server itself is not so secure.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these libraries in your Python application to talk to the SSHD daemon on the server:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell

You'll want to look at something that will help you set up SSHD in a secure manner like this:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8759

You will also need to ensure that you update the SSHD daemon regularly and make use of keys and strong, rotating passwords. All this should be standard for a telnet application too, but due to the lack of transport level encryption, you really shouldn't be using telnet for anything.